# BaseClientService does not contain a definition of Files

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have problem using the DriveService from google Nuget package (Google.Apis.Drive.v3).

I get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'BaseClientService' does not contain a definition for 'Files' and no extension method 'Files' accepting a first argument of type 'BaseClientService' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Sampleproject.Web   C:\sample\Sampleproject.Web\Controllers\DriveController.cs  117 Active

[image]

I'm using parts of the guide from the official documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet#step_1_turn_on_the_api_name

Initially i thought it was just a "usings" that i was missing, but i can't seem to figure out/google my way to which it is.

**Edit:**

My service looks like this:
[image]

And my usercredentials looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you created your `service` but you can try:

I am going to guess you are doing something like this.

```
// Create Drive API service.
var service  = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Drive Authentication Sample",
    };
```

In which case you should be declaring the service like this.

```
// Create Drive API service.
var service  = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
     HttpClientInitializer = credential,
     ApplicationName = "Drive Authentication Sample",
     });
```

**Update:**

Part of your problem could be that you are mixing V2 and V3.

```
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
```

List:

```
var pageStreamer = new PageStreamer<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File, FilesResource.ListRequest, Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.FileList, string>(
                                                   (request, token) => request.PageToken = token,
                                                   response => response.NextPageToken,
                                                   response => response.Files);

var req = service.Files.List();
req.PageSize = 1000;


foreach (var result in pageStreamer.Fetch(req))
     {
     Console.WriteLine(result.Id);
     }
```

Comment: Check update might want to pick an api version and not use both.